# How can I write an EDN line by line? (spit, seq of hashmaps)

Tags: clojure, writefile, line-by-line

I have data like that

```
tab = ({"123" data} {"456" data} ...
```

(whatever, it is a lazy sequence of hashmaps).

I want to write it into an edn file line by line, so I did this

```
(map (fn[x] (spit "test.edn" x :append true)) tab)
```

The problem is that I would like to have this in the file :

```
{"123" data}
{"456" data}
```

But it seems to append like that

```
{"123" data}{"456" data}
```

Is there a way to solve this ? 
I guess I have to add "newline" but I don't know how to do it since inputs are not strings.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(doseq [x tab]
  (spit "test.edn" (prn-str x) :append true))
```

So, for each item in `tab`, convert it to a readable string followed by a newline, then append that string to `test.edn`.

You should not use `map` for this for a couple of reasons:

1. `map` is lazy and therefore will not print the entire sequence unless you force it
2. `map` retains the head of the sequence, which would simply waste memory here

Comment: Thanks ! Haven't tried yet because my thing is working but will have a look when my final program will work for improvement !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I finally found it, hope it will help some people beauce I did not find it in the internet (I mean no simple answer).

```
(map (fn[x] (spit "test.edn" (str x "\n") :append true)) tab)
```

Good afternoon.

Comment: You should use `pr-str` and not just `str`. Eg, It will properly work with `nil`.

Comment: doseq is better since spit is a side-effect function